# Select rows into columns with grouping

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have few tables:

```
     Exams 
     UserExams 
     UserExamQuestions 
     UserExamAnswers 
     Users 
     ExamQuestions 
     ExamQuestionAnswers
```

this is select I developed

```
    select ue.DateStarted as 'Date Started', u.LastName as 'Lastname', 
    u.FirstName as 'Firstname', eq.Text as 'Question', eqa.Text as 'Answer',
    eqa.IsCorrect as 'Correct' from Exams e
    join UserExams ue on ue.ExamId = e.Id
    join UserExamQuestions ueq on ueq.UserExamId = ue.Id
    join UserExamAnswers uea on uea.UserExamQuestionId = ueq.Id
    join Users u on u.Id = ue.UserId
    join ExamQuestions eq on eq.Id = ueq.ExamQuestionId
    join ExamQuestionAnswers eqa on eqa.Id = uea.ExamQuestionAnswerId
    where e.Id = 10 and uea.IsSelected = 1
    order by u.LastName, u.FirstName
```

but unfortunately it returns data in unwanted way. Returned row looks like this

```
    Date Started            Lastname  Firstname      Question             Answer         Correct
    2012-02-26 13:29:50.770 Somename  Somefirstname  Some question text?  Some answer   0
    2012-02-26 13:30:20.000 Othername Otherfirstname Some question text?  Some answer   0
    2012-02-26 15:10:10.212 Fifth     Fifthname      Some question text?  Other answer  1
```

Of course above example is for three users, who answered one question with some answers. Selected data is fine, but I need it to be like this:

```
   Lastname  Firstname       [Some question text?] Correct
   Somename  Somefirstname   Some answer           0
   Othername Otherfirstname  Some answer           0
   Fifth     Fifthname       Other answer          1
```

Is it possible? It does not has to be fast. Doing it in code behind will be pain... I was trying pivot, but firstly - I don't think I understand it correctly, and secondly I don't want to aggregate data.

Thanks for help.

Comment: what is difference in expected and  the result you are getting ? date is not there in expected.. from question title..are you looking for group by Answer ?

Comment: Date is irrelevant. I don't know what the answer is. In result and expected first row is column names, and other rows are values. I want to rotate all Questions into columns and display answers selected by user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So I did see you answer and I have a suggestion for you. You where actually correct when you said that you where going to do this with a pivot.

So first I did simplified your data for testing purpose. The test data is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    Lastname VARCHAR(100),  
    Firstname VARCHAR(100),
    Answer VARCHAR(100),
    Question VARCHAR(100),
    Correct BIT
)
INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES
  ('Somename','Somefirstname','Some answer','Some question text?',0),
  ('Somename','Somefirstname','Answer to second question','Second question in same column?',1),
  ('Othername','Otherfirstname','Some answer','Some question text?',0),
  ('Othername','Otherfirstname','Wrong answer to second question','Second question in same column?',0),
  ('Fifth','Fifthname','Other answer','Some question text?',1),
  ('Fifth','Fifthname','Wrong answer to second question','Second question in same column?',0)
```

The you need to get the unique columns to pivot on. Like this:

```
DECLARE @Questions VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Question ORDER BY Question) AS RowNbr,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Question) AS OrderBy,
    Table1.Question
  FROM
    Table1
), CTE2
AS
(
  SELECT
    CTE.OrderBy AS OrderBy,
    1 AS SecondOrder,
    CTE.Question
  FROM
    CTE
  WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    CTE.OrderBy AS OrderBy,
    2 AS SecondOrder,
    'Is '+CTE.Question
  FROM
    CTE
  WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
)
SELECT
  @Questions = COALESCE(@Questions + ','+QUOTENAME(Question),
                     QUOTENAME(Question))
FROM
  CTE2
ORDER BY
  CTE2.OrderBy,
  CTE2.SecondOrder
```

- The first `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Question ORDER BY Question)` is to get the unique columns. I will use it later with the `where` statement.
- The second `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Question)` is to order the questions
- The `SecondOrder` is so that you will order the question before the "Is" questions
- The `UNION ALL` is so that we can `UNION ALL` the question and "Is" questions
- The `@Questions = COALESCE(@Questions + ','+QUOTENAME(Question),`.. Concats the columns to one `varchar`

Then we need to make some dynamic sql for the pivot and at the end execute it. Like this:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N';WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
    Table1.Lastname,
    Table1.Firstname,
    Table1.Answer,
    Table1.Question
  FROM
    Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    Table1.Lastname,
    Table1.Firstname,
    CAST(Table1.Correct AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Answer,
    ''Is ''+Table1.Question AS Question
  FROM
    Table1
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    CTE.Lastname,
    CTE.Firstname,
    CTE.Answer,
    CTE.Question
  FROM
    CTE
) AS p
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Answer)
    FOR Question IN ('+@Questions+')
) AS pvt'
EXECUTE(@query)
```

- Then we need to `UNION ALL` the questions with the "Is" questions
- The `Correct` column is cast to `VARCHAR` because a `UNION ALL` and a pivot do not allow different data types
- The we will use a `MAX` aggregate to get the answer we need. This is because a pivot require us to use a aggregate.
- The `FOR Question IN ('+@Questions+')` is the columns that we concated in the query above.

You can see the result and the example data [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8429d/36)

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you! It is a good lead :) but it still works only if there is one question in exam. What if Exam has several questions?

Comment: Thanks for your effort :) I will answer below, because it will take more than 600 characters.

Comment: Updated the answer. Take a look :P

Comment: It's brilliant! You're brilliant! Many Kudos for you! It works, like a charm :) Do you have any idea why, when I change script to work on #tmpTable it does not return correct results? Also when I change it to use @tmpTable script does not see it in execute(query)...

Comment: You can not execute dynamic sql on a declared table (@table). It should return the same if you change to a #table. If you replace it everywhere.

Comment: If you want people to answer your questions. It is nice if you vote up the answer you accepted :). Then the person answer the question gets something for doing that :P

Comment: About @table I figured it out, but #table I am still investigating... I suppose error is on my side. Of course I vote up your answer - just didn't know I should :)

Comment: it's just s nice thing to do for the effort. If you have a problem with the #table. You can always ask a new question:). I hope you solve it happy coding:P

Answer (score 2):

Arion - your script fetches all the question into one column like this:

```
   Lastname  Firstname       [Some question text?,Second question in same column?] Correct
   Somename  Somefirstname   Some answer                                           0
   Somename  Somefirstname   Answer to second question                             1
   Othername Otherfirstname  Some answer                                           0
   Othername Otherfirstname  Wrong answer to second question                       0
   Fifth     Fifthname       Other answer                                          1
   Fifth     Fifthname       Wrong answer to second question                       0
```

What I would need is like this:

```
   Lastname  Firstname       [Some question text?] [Is Some question answer correct]  [Second question in same column?] [Is Second question in same column answer correct] 
   Somename  Somefirstname   Some answer           0                                  Answer to second question         1          
   Othername Otherfirstname  Some answer           0                                  Wrong answer to second question   0                             
   Fifth     Fifthname       Other answer          1                                  Wrong answer to second question   0
```

Comment: That looks like a challenge to get that results. I will try to answer you later this day